# Python Coverage Warning - Module 'module_name' was not imported by the covered tests

Tags: python, coverage.py, pybuilder

I am getting an error promoting  `[WARN]  Module 'module_name' was not imported by the covered tests` in pybuild python coverage plugin.

I can't see my scripts in coverage report and build got success with high coverage rate showing 100% coverage in `__init__.py` scripts.
[image]

I have written some unit tests to some of my modules and executed in `pyunit`. 
[image]
But the coverage report does not contain that information. When I disable `unittesting` report is generated for all the scripts.

[image]

what is the problem with this.

Comment: Have you made any progress on that? I can confirm that it prints this warning on every module for a "reasonably looking" project, and does not seem to do anything meaningful otherwise.